# How to modify array under condition without copying, code should not use any extra space and should be as efficient as possible?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify array elements under a condition, and then remove duplicates.

Here's my code:

```
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 1];
arr = arr.map(item => item > 2 ? 0 : item); // zero elements larger than 2
arr = Array.from(new Set(arr)); // remove duplicates
console.log(arr);
```

Result:

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

Although this works, it is copying the modified array which I think is not ideal.

Is there a way to make the code more elegant and performant?

Comment: Do you want same array to be changed?

Comment: @AkshayBande I want whatever is more performant

Comment: how many records in your array? I do not think the end-user can tell the difference whether you copy the array or modify it directly. I think you are doing it ok. Also by mutating the original array this may affect other places in your code that use the array.

Comment: If you're asking about performance then change the title to reflect that.  What you actually asked for was how to modify an array without copying.

Comment: I think your code is good enough.

Comment: *"I think is not ideal"* ...why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `reduce`. Here's an example, which is not elegant, but gets the job done:

```
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 1];

let add_zero = false;

const out = arr.reduce((s, i) => {
  if (i <= 2) {
    s.add(i);
  } else if (!add_zero) {
    add_zero = true;
  }
  return s;
}, new Set());

if (add_zero) {
  out.add(0);
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use any extra space and mutate the same array.

```js
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1];
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] > 2) {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}
arr = arr.sort();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let j = i;
  while (arr[j] == arr[j + 1]) {
    arr.splice(j, 1);
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```